# Why does my Red Acer plant look like it has twigs but no leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, maple

I have two Red Acer plants. They were both young and small when I bought them last year. I did find some bugs on the branches of the green one, so I sprayed them with bug spray. The one with the green leaves looks okay now. The bugs are gone and it has new leaf growth, but there's nothing on the red one, just twigs without leaves. It seems as if it has buds, but they haven't developed into leaves.

What can I do to try and save it? I'd put pictures of them here but don't know how to attach pictures on this link.

Comment: Click on camera or picture icon then upload or take a picture. Caption is optional.

Comment: Welcome to the site zena!  In case you have trouble getting back into your question, just press on the small gray word "edit" on the bottom.  You can then add the requested information from the answer below. Follow the instructions from @Danger14 to add the pictures, and you'll be all set. I'll get you started by giving you the option to [edit] right from here. Our site's a bit different from others, so please check out our [help]. If you still need anything, leave us a note. We hope to see you often!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if the red leaved one has died over winter - they do get dieback quite often, and in a small plant, that might be what's happened. Scrape back a little of the bark covering near the base of the plant with your fingernail - if its brown and dry beneath, then its definitely dead. You haven't said where you are in the world, nor whether these plants were in pots or in the ground, but maybe the red leaved one went short of water at some point.